# Highcharts in the Rails Assest Pipeline not Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, asset-pipeline

I'm working in development and am migrating from Rails 3.x to Rails 4.2.5 with Ruby 2.1.  In the previous version of rails, Highcharts was working perfectly. Now I am trying to use the asset pipeline for the first time.

Within my applcation.html.erb file, I have included the line:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Within assets/javascripts, I've verified the file "application.js" exists.  Within that file I have included the lines:

```
 //= require jquery.min
 //= require rails
 //= require highcharts
 //= require_tree .
```

I have verified the files just listed above also exist in the asset/javascript.  I thought that was all I needed, but I always get a blank screen when I try to display the chart. The log file says the view with the chart was rendered, but nothing is displayed. It worked perfectly in the previous version of rails, so I am ruling out the creation, handling and data values of the chart as being the source of the problem.

So what else am I missing to get Highcharts to run again?  If more info is needed to help answer the question, please just let me know.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's `//* require rails` doing in `application.js`? That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @MarsAtomic - I removed
    //* require rails 

and restarted the server.  Still comes up blank though.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't expect that would fix the problem -- it's a separate issue. I don't know anything about Highcharts, but the gem's git page does seem to suggest that there may be dependencies in the form of modules. Are you loading everything your implementation needs?

Comment: @MarsAtomic - that would be the essential question.  No errors are being thrown and the server output file says it has rendered the view, but nothing is displayed.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Also, just to clarify for readers at this point:  I am not using the Highcharts-rails gem as provided here: 

      [link](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails)

Although I have tried it and received the same blank screen for a results

Comment: I use Highcharts with Rails 4.2.3 with no issues, so that's not the problem. You won't find anything in the server log, but have a look at the browser's console for errors. I assume you have some JavaScript files where you have put all the configuration for Highcharts?

Comment: @taglia - the files that I listed in my original post as "required" all exist in the asset\pipeline\javascripts subdirectory if that is what you're asking.  Although oddly enough, when I open a browser console, per your suggestion, at the bottom of the console window, the comments from application.js are printed, but nothing after that. Shouldn't that confirm that any js files were loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  There was an extra comma buried within my Highcharts function call.  I was able to find this by using @taglia comments about using a browser console, which in the future I will know to use as part of my debugging tool box.

Thanks to everyone for your help and insights.